# Use from "php - $_GET[]" and "RewriteRule" in "htaccess" for "d.com" and "d.com/p/1"

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

---

**Mode 1 :** 
**URL:** `domain.com/?sv=g` 
**.htaccess:** `RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ fa/?page=$1` 
When I use from `$_GET['sv']` return to me `g`.

---

**Mode 2 :** 
**URL:** `domain.com/page/1/?sv=g` 
**.htaccess:**  `RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ fa/?page=$1` 
When I use from `$_GET['sv']` return to me `null`.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the [`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag to your RewriteRule, or it won't add in any existing query string paramters from the request:

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ fa/?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**.htaccess :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ fa/?page=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)$ fa/?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Read this : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa